# Sql Update Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

```
UPDATE trainerdetails 
SET trainerdetails.login_code='100' 
WHERE trainerdetails.empname=admin.[name]
```

This is my Sql Syntax I want to update `login_code`. I have two tables

1. for Admin
2. for all user including admin

I just want to give the login code to multiple type of user(eg admin='100' employee='200') but this update query is not working. This is what the error I am facing:

> The multi-part identifier "admin.name" could not be bound.

And select Query for same table is working

```
SELECT trainerdetails.tid
  ,trainerdetails.trid
  ,trainerdetails.login_code
  ,trainerdetails.empname 
FROM trainerdetails,admin 
WHERE trainerdetails.empname=admin.[name]
```

Comment: On a side-note: avoid the use of [Old Style JOINS](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 1):

This is the syntax in SQL Server:

```
update td
    set login_code = '100' 
    from trainderdetails td join
         admin a 
         on td.empname = a.[name];
```